# I'm trying to use a holder in android studio but 'holder.sentMessage.text' keeps throwing an error. I'm a beginner so i would appreciate your support

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

['text' keeps on throwing an error Unresolved reference: text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhUdp.png)

Answer (score 0):

In line no 40 you've defined as a TextureView instead of a TextView.

Your Textview should have the TextView inside the <> to work

In your case it will be

```
val sentmessage = itemview.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_sent_message)
```